# Executing or closing program based on file contents

Tags: c#, .net

So my program is a simple form that a user has to read, agree to the terms, and close the window. When the user closes the window it takes their login name and date / time, writes it to a txt file and exits. When the program loads, I want it to check the file for the existing username. If it finds the username, check the date on which it was recorded and if it was within 6 months exit the program. If it was recorded more than 6 months ago, run the program. Obviously, if the reading of the file doesn't find the username I want the program to run as well. Here is my code so far -

```
namespace EUSAA
{
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        txtUsername.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        btnClose.Visible = false;
        chkAgree.Visible = true;
        rtbSecurityAwareness.LoadFile("Security Awareness.rtf");
    }

    private void chkAgree_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkAgree.Checked)
        {
            btnClose.Visible = true;
        }
        else btnClose.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"I:\Security Awareness Signed Users\Signed Users.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? You can just go through every line, split by "\t" and check the date

Comment: Plz tell us what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Couldn't you just save this in a boolean field in user settings?

Comment: Why `Environment.Exit(0)`? Why not `this.Close()`?

Comment: @Greg Maybe it's some kind of a log file which he want to open and look at what and when someone opened the program. There might me hundreds of different users.

Comment: Unrelated tip: you can rewrite `chkAgree_CheckedChanged` as simply `btnClose.Visible = chkAgree.Checked;` (nothing else required).

Comment: I'd also suggest just storing the date (i.e. `DateTime.Today` rather than `DateTime.Now`), if you only need a date; but whether you do that or not, I'd suggest using `.ToString("O")` which is the [Roundtrip format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip), and will avoid culture-related issues when reading the value (e.g. whether 02/12/2018 is December the 2nd or 12th February).

Comment: Hey guys, so I haven't coded in a while and kind of just needed some guidance as to the syntax of what I wanted to do. So, I want to read line by line of the file and compare the date written in the file and whether that date is 6 months from today's date (being whenever the program runs). If the date is more than 6 months then run the program, if not just exit the program.

Comment: @Dave_M As this is your first non-duplicate question, you may want to take a moment to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Feel free to [Edit] your question or add a comment to an answer if it isn't quite what you're looking for, explaining what's not right.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a code writing site; but I was feeling generous. The following class encapsulates storing and retrieving the latest agreement for the current user.

```
public class AgreementRepository
{
    private const string FileLocation = @"I:\Security Awareness Signed Users\Signed Users.txt";
    private const char Separator = '\t';

    public void AppendAgreementForCurrentUser()
    {
        string currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(FileLocation))
        {
            sw.WriteLine($"{currentUser}{Separator}{DateTime.Now:O}");
        }
    }

    public DateTime? GetLastAgreementForCurrentUser()
    {
        string currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
        if (File.Exists(FileLocation) == false)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var lastAgreement = File.ReadLines(FileLocation)
            .Select(x => x.Split(Separator))
            .Where(x => x.Length == 2 && string.Equals(x[0], currentUser, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Select(x => GetDateTime(x[1]))
            .Max();
        return lastAgreement;
    }

    private static DateTime? GetDateTime(string input)
    {
        DateTime result;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static string GetCurrentUser()
    {
        return System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    }
}
```

To use this, your form would become...

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private readonly AgreementRepository _agreementRepository;

    public frmMain()
    {
        _agreementRepository = new AgreementRepository();

        InitializeComponent();
        txtDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        txtUsername.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        btnClose.Visible = false;
        chkAgree.Visible = true;
        rtbSecurityAwareness.LoadFile("Security Awareness.rtf");

        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lastAgreement = _agreementRepository.GetLastAgreementForCurrentUser();
        // NOTE: The following condition deals with the fact that lastAgreement could be null
        if (lastAgreement > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
        {
            Close(); // or Environment.Exit; depends what you need
        }
    }

    private void chkAgree_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnClose.Visible = chkAgree.Checked; // simplification of your posted code
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _agreementRepository.AppendAgreementForCurrentUser();
        Environment.Exit(0); // Would 'Close()' be enough?
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I forgot to use the DateTimeStyles.RoundTrip overload when doing the DateTime Parse; but I'm away from my computer now, so can't test the correction. I'm sure you'll work it out; and it will probably work as it stands.